# Prevent repositioning of nav whet initializing jquery mmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, mmenu

Is it possible to prevent mmenu from being moved to the top of the page during initialization?

I have some inner div on my page. Inside this div I define `<nav>`...`</nav>` for my mmenu.

However when I initialize mmenu in javascript whole `<nav>` tag gets moved outside of my div to the top of the page.

Can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can *Prevent Flash Of Unstyled Content* (F.O.U.C.) and hide the menu while it has not yet received the *mm-menu* classname with this CSS entry :

```
#my-menu:not(.mm-menu) {display: none}
```

That is one of the ["Tips and Tricks"](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/support/tips-and-tricks.html) on the **MMENU** website.